# gcc linux-64 compiler version 8.4 on RHEL 7 - undefined symbol clock_gettime@GLIBC_2.17

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, conda, rhel7

I have a conda environment on RHEL containing:

```
# platform: linux-64
_sysroot_linux-64_curr_repodata_hack=3=haa98f57_10
binutils_impl_linux-64=2.35.1=h27ae35d_9
binutils_linux-64=2.35.1=h454624a_30
gcc_impl_linux-64=8.4.0=he7ac559_17
gcc_linux-64=8.4.0=he201b7d_30
gxx_impl_linux-64=8.4.0=h9ce2e92_17
gxx_linux-64=8.4.0=h85ed34b_30
kernel-headers_linux-64=2.6.32=h77966d4_13
ld_impl_linux-64=2.35.1=h7274673_9
libgcc-devel_linux-64=8.4.0=hd257e2f_17
libstdcxx-devel_linux-64=8.4.0=hf0c5c8d_17
sysroot_linux-64=2.12=h77966d4_13
libgcc-ng=9.3.0=h2828fa1_19
```

I am trying to compile a simple c++ program containing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
   timespec ts;
   (void)clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
   return 0;
}
```

However I keep on getting undefined symbol errors:

```
/home/idzero/condaenvs/npy37/CondaInstall/envs/npy37/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/8.4.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/idzero/condaenvs/npy37/CondaInstall/envs/npy37/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/8.4.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/lib/../lib/libstdc++.so: undefined reference to `clock_gettime@GLIBC_2.17'
/home/idzero/condaenvs/npy37/CondaInstall/envs/npy37/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/8.4.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/idzero/condaenvs/npy37/CondaInstall/envs/npy37/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/8.4.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/lib/../lib/libstdc++.so: undefined reference to `aligned_alloc@GLIBC_2.16'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My compile command line is:

```
${CONDA_PREFIX}/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-g++ ./a.cpp -lrt
```

This gcc compiler metapackage  consists of the following libraries (among others - all v2.12)

```
libc-2.12.so
ld-2.12.so
librt-2.12.so
libstdc++.so.6.0.25
```

Intestingly libstdc++.so.6.0.25 points to ../../../lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.25 which doesn't exist. Instead there is ../../../lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.28!

Can someone please help me with two questions I have?

- why does libstdc++ in a conda environment that doesn't come with 2.17 libc reference a symbol in that library?
- How do I build in this environment?

I'd like to add that if I the system library path /lib64 and link explicitly against libc-2.17, I am able to compile successfully.
So

${CONDA_PREFIX}/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-g++ ./a.cpp -L/lib64 -lc-2.17

works. But it doesn't seem right to have to explicitly link against libc-2.17.

Setting the sysroot to / through

```
g++ -Wl,--sysroot=/ a.cpp
```

works. But then it links against the system supplied libc, which of course defeats the sandboxes environment provided by conda.